# The annihilator of the span of linear functionals is equal to the intersection of the kernals?

Tags: linear-algebra

i came up with this thought:

let $V$ be a Vector Space over a field $F, \space\space  \varphi^{1},...\varphi^{k}\in V^{\lor}$

Is it true that the $(Span(\varphi^{1},\ldots,\varphi^{k}))_{0}=\bigcap_{i=1}^{k}ker(\varphi^{i})$   ?

no need to prove, just sanity check, thank you!

Comment: Oh, I'm taking advantage of this question for the following: it is being a trend (in my eyes, at least) in the Hebrew University's currect linear algebra II course this year to denote by $\;V^V\;$ what I always knew as $\;V^*:=$ the linear space of linear functionals on a linear space $\;V\;$ . Is this a more or less widely used (modern) notation, or someone's gone bananas in my beloved university and invented out of the blue the rather ugly notation $\;V^V\;$ ?

Comment: not only in this year....

Comment: Hehe...I know, Amit: after a while we all go banans for mathematics. It's fun.

Comment: @Timbuc I saw this notation in Loring W Tu's Intro to Manifolds, for one.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Thanks. Perhaps it's a little more common than what I thought, but still I think the other one, i.e. $\;V^*\;$ is much more widely used.

Answer (score 1):

Both inclusions are pretty obvious. (If in a linear combination of linear forms each term vanishes on a given vector, so does the entire linear combination. For vectors for which all such linear combinations vanish, the individual $\varphi^i$ vanish in particular.)